# how to merge two consecutive records in a Data Frame in Python Based on Condition

Tags: python, nlp

I have a data frame like below:

[image]

i want to merge all consecutive clauses in clauses calumn which has False value in the column['clauses_last_word_chk'], then delete the row after merging,and keep the row which have True in the column['clauses_last_word_chk']

For example :
the first three rows have False values to be merged, then delete second and third rows.
the 4th, 5th,6th will remain the same without merging.
the 7th and 8th rows to be merged, then delete the 8th row as below:

[image]

below is my code:

```
for i in range (0,len(general_df)):
    if (general_df['clauses_last_word_chk'][i]==False) and i<len(general_df):
        
        general_df['clauses_merged'][i]=str(general_df['clauses'][i])+','+str(general_df['clauses'][i+1])
        general_df.drop( general_df['clauses_merged'][i+1], inplace=True)
    else:
        general_df['clauses_merged'][i]=general_df['clauses'][i]
```

Comment: Please don't post images. Post sample input and expected output as text.

Comment: @Ahmed Safwat Ewida why does 7th and 8th rows need to be merged because it contradicts with your requirement earlier - "i want to merge all consecutive clauses in clauses calumn which has False value in the column['clauses_last_word_chk']"

Comment: yes, I want to merge also the rows if the ['clauses_last_word_chk']=False and the value in the next row equal = True

Answer (score 1):

i Got the answer as below:

```
fil = general_df['clauses_last_word_chk'].ne(False).cumsum()
ccc = general_df.groupby(fil).agg({'Article':'first','clauses':','.join})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the rows that have False value in a column, you can do the following instead of merging all such rows and deleting that row.

```
general_df = general_df[general_df['clauses_last_word_chk'] == True]
```

This lets you filter the rows with a False value in the clauses_last_word_chk column and without having to merge them.

Comment: I Want to merge the consecutive clauses which have false values, and keep the clauses which have true values as it is without merging,and keep the same sequence

Comment: A sample input and required output would be really helpful here. It's a little difficult to understand the question. You mentioned in the description that you want to delete the clauses with False value after merging that's why I suggested filtering.